# How do I do duo-colour dashes?

Tags: inkscape

I've been trying to edit a SVG diagram ([here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1_sXH68hMWBTTV5eHkzVkdaRDg/view?usp=sharing) in my Google Drive you can find it if having the original SVG helps you in assisting me), below is a PNG bitmap of the original labelling what I want changed.

If you zoom where I've labelled (1), or any other places where the pink arc intersects with the dashed line, you will see that while I've lowered the pink arc so that whenever it intersects with the brown line (i.e., the dashed one) it is hidden under the brown line. The problem is that since it is dashed the pink arc is still being displayed whenever they intersect a gap. So what I would like to know is how I can overcome this problem. I'd also like to know how I can convert the gaps in the dashed brown line into a new set of dashes, but of a different colour to the colour of the original dashes (i.e., brown) so that there is no white space here any more.

[image]

Comment: Remember that you can also upvote answers you accept – or, in the rare case that you think that an answer does not deserve your upvote, explain why this is the case. By not doing so, you may decrease the motivation of others to answer your and other people’s questions. (I am not remarking this for purely egoistic reasons. There are at least three Stack Exchanges, on which you have accepted more answers than you have cast votes on answers.)

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574787/svg-css-stroke-dashed-line-with-two-colors-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a duplicate of your dashed path.
2. Make it white (or any colour you desire).
3. Make it solid (not dashed).
4. Lower it such that it is behind your dashed path but above everything else.

Thus, everything you see of your new path is between the dashes of your dashed path and it covers all “intrusions” of the pink paths.